# How to change sidebar height and tab height manually in JetBrains WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I just recently found out that JetBrains released the `2021` version of WebStorm so I update it and it changed my entire UI because `Material UI` is not `free` anymore but at anyhow I managed it but I got a problem with the height of my `left sidebar` and `editor tabs`.

`Editor tabs` become too small in `height and width` and don't show the `full name` of the `file` sometimes ( see `package.json` and `.eslintrc` in image ) and the `left sidebar` looks like all things are much much together.

Please help me to change the height of the `editor tabs` and `sidebar` or How to get `Material Theme UI` for free

**WebStorm 2020**

[image]

**WebStorm 2021**

[image]

Comment: Does the issue only occur when using **Material Theme UI** plugin?

Comment: check I added same image with `v2020` and `v2021`

Comment: @lena my question is now how can I change height of the editor tabs and sidebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that after installing `v2020`, You can change the `Editor Tabs` height with the help of `Material Theme UI` and also change the sidebar height

That's why after uninstalling `Material Theme UI` I got a problem of scaling

**Editor Tabs Height Setting**

> Appearance & Behavior > Material Theme > Tabs > Tabs Height

**Sidebar Height Setting**

> Appearance & Behavior > Material Theme > Project View > Custom Sidebar Height

So thats why I downgrade the version of the `Material Theme UI` to `5.7.0` and my all problem is solved.

You can download it from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?rel=true&updateId=109027

```
1. Download the zip
2. Open plugins from settings and click on 3 vertical dots near to `Installed` and then click on `install plugin from disk`.
3. Select above downloaded zip
4. Enjoy
```

Github: https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/issues/1718